# Predicate to Match Multiple Properties of Array of Custom Objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, batch-processing, nspredicate

I am trying to match an array of custom objects to another array of custom objects.  I am using CoreData, where I store some `Person` objects.  I then download and create another array of custom objects of type `OnlinePerson`.  I need to filter my array of locally-stored `Person` and change their 'isFriend' bool value to true.

As template code, say these are the two classes:

```
class Person{
    var name : String!
    var surname : String!
    var houseNumber : Int!
    var isFriend : Bool! = false
    init(name : String, surname : String, houseNumber : Int){
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.houseNumber = houseNumber
    }
}

class OnlinePerson{
    var name : String!
    var surname : String!
    var houseNumber : Int!
    init(name : String, surname : String, houseNumber : Int){
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.houseNumber = houseNumber
    }
}
```

And then add some dummy data:

```
var localPersons = [Person]()

for i in 0..<10{
    localPersons.append(Person(name: "John \(i)", surname: "Doe \(i * 2)", houseNumber: i))
}

var onlinePersons = [OnlinePerson]()

// Add some items that should match locally
for i in 0..<5{
    onlinePersons.append(OnlinePerson(name: "John \(i)", surname: "Doe \(i * 2)", houseNumber : i))
}

// Add new items
for i in 0..<5{
    onlinePersons.append(OnlinePerson(name: "John \(i)", surname: "Doe \(i)", houseNumber: i*3))
}
```

I tried to use this `NSPredicate`, which worked fine in Playgrounds but does not work with CoreData as you cannot use block predicates with CoreData:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (person, dict) -> Bool in

    if let person = person as? Person{

        for onlinePerson in onlinePersons{

            if person.name == onlinePerson.name && person.surname == onlinePerson.surname && person.houseNumber == onlinePerson.houseNumber{
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}

let results = localPersons.filter({ predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) })
```

How would I create an `NSPredicate` to achieve such a task?  I've searched around but all I can find are answers that match arrays of `String`s (, not arrays of custom objects.

Currently, as a temporary solution, I fetch all `Person` objects using a regular NSFetchRequest.  Then I match them with the downloaded `OnlinePerson` objects, and if they match, set isFriend to true, otherwise set it to false.  Then I save the context.  However, I've read this is more efficient via batch updates rather than fetching and matching every single `Person` object.

In the end, I'd like all local Person objects that match the downloaded OnlinePerson objects to be marked as isFriend = true.  And the ones that don't match, mark it as false.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Neither of those classes can be used with Core Data, at least as you've presented them here. How are you saving a `Person` to Core Data?

Comment: @TomHarrington Ah sorry for the confusion, I was just trying to solve this problem in Playgrounds with regular classes.  My actual use case is very similar and has appropriate NSManaged properties :)